# How to create /usr/texbin?

Tags: installing, texlive, mactex

I am a mac user but I have installed the TeX Live distribution without the help of MacTeX. The directory `/usr/texbin` is missing and TeXShop or TeXworks won't compile.

I know that I can change the path to the bin in these applications, but I would prefer creating a `/usr/texbin` (is it a symbolic link?) similar to the one created by MacTeX.

PS : Why do I am in this situation ? I wanted to update my installation to 2013. So, I downloaded the big `.iso` file of the TeXLive distribution. But, TeXShop was still accessing the 2012 folder... So I removed this one, etc.

Comment: I ended up downloading `MacTeX`. I leave the question open; it might interest someone. As for me, I solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can easily change the path for the TeX programs also with TeXShop and TeXworks; just make them point to `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin`; the drawback is that you need to change this at every installation. MacTeX does this for you by creating an infrastructure in `/Library/TeX` and making a symbolic link `/usr/texbin` that's managed by the installer or by the TeX distribution pane in the System Preferences.

If you don't want to download MacTeX and prefer to directly install TeX Live, you can create the symbolic link yourself by

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin /usr/texbin
```

(change `x86_64-darwin` to `universal-darwin` if you don't have a 64 bit system); just remember to do

```
sudo rm /usr/texbin
```

as soon as you install a new release, before creating the symbolic link again.

Comment: Since El Capitan this no longer works. You can not create symlinks anymore because of the so-called "rootless" mode. (See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196224/unix-ln-s-command-not-permitted-in-osx-el-capitan-beta3). A solution is to symlink to `/usr/local/texbin` and set it up in your `.zshrc` or w/e.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer MacTeX sets up a link in a different place; see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/mac-os-changes-that-affect-lots-of-answers

Answer (score 1):

Applicable only to El Capitan Final release and Later OS...

As @ChristopheDeTroyer mentioned, since El Capitan, symbolic links cannot be created because of the rootless mode. There are 2 ways to get rid of this and similar problems:

1. Disable the **rootless** mode ([this is how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590053/copying-file-under-root-got-failed-in-os-x-el-capitan-10-11/32590885#32590885)) and then add the symbolic link using
    `sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin /usr/texbin`. You can re-enable the **rootless** mode  if you want.
2. Change each and every path of your editor to `usr/local/texlive/XXXX/bin/x86_64-darwin`, where `XXXX` is the version of your MacTex Distribution. For this problem, it would be either `2015` or `2016` as this workaround applies only to El Capitan and later Mac Oses.  I use tex-studio  and I just had to set the paths once and that's it.