# Recreating /usr/texbin after OS upgrade

Tags: mactex

I recently upgraded from Lion (OS X 10.7.5) to OS X 10.9.5 (Yosemite? Mavericks?). I previously had run a MacTeX package, so I had the packages in whatever folder, and the `/usr/texbin` directory. The former is still there, but the latter has vanished. The whole package would exhaust my mobile data traffic, since I have about 2GB and the package is 2615436KB. Is it possible to only download `texbin` in order to place it in `usr`and get back to using TeX with some mobile data left?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/texbin` is only an alias for the path to the current TeX distribution binaries, not a directory. And this alias has been replaced by `/Library/TeX/texbin` in the most recent versions of MacTeX. In TeXShop, for instance, the path indicated in the Preferences to go to the TeX binaries is `/Library/TeX/texbin` and not `/usr/texbin` anymore. This may explain your problem.

Comment: How recent? I mean, I read an answer about that which stated that from Mac 10.10 on there is a problem with accessing usr, but I have 10.9, and the fact that trying to typeset produces "xelatex command not found" on the console suggests that my version had the usr/texbin or if it had the Library/TeX thing it got deleted too, but why would that be deleted and the packages be left where they are? They are in Library too, right?

Comment: All of TeX Live is in `/usr/local/texlive/****`, where `****` is the distribution year. `/Library/TeX/texbin` is an alias (symbolic link) for `/usr/local/texlive/****/bin`. By the way, have you also updated MacTeX?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is since MacTeX 2015 that the symbolic link to the binaries has changed. The reason was something that concerned the then new system Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11). Your own system, 10.9, is Mavericks, so it was not concerned a priori. It may be that the `/usr/texbin` symbolic link has been lost during your update. If so, this subject may be of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137116/how-to-create-usr-texbin

Comment: Yep, that was it. Now it's typesetting.